# Using SELECT inside of SELECT is returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to generate a list of payments owed to members and affiliates.

The `statistics` stable has these columns:

```
id, revenue, member, referral, date
```

Here's my current code:

```
SELECT
   member,
   SUM(revenue) AS payment,
   (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM statistics WHERE referral = member AND date BETWEEN '04/01/2019' and '04/31/2019') AS aff_earnings,
   (SELECT paypal FROM members WHERE id = member) AS paypal 
FROM
   statistics 
WHERE
   date BETWEEN '04/01/2019' and '04/31/2019' 
GROUP BY
   member
```

I am getting the correct results for `member`, `payment`, and `paypal`.  However,  `aff_earnings` is returning `null` for all results.

For each `member`, I want to get the total amount of revenue they've generated that month.  That's correct as displayed as `payment`.

However, I also want to get the total amount that any of their referrals have generated.  Their referrals can be founding by searching for that member's ID in the `referral` column.

I'm trying to output that amount as `aff_earnings` but not really sure why it's coming back as `null` :/

Comment: please share sample data and expected output

Comment: @Stacker I would also recommend changing the `s.date` column name. "Date" is a special word in most flavors of SQL. Something as simple as `sDate` would be preferable and less error-prone than just `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries, but if they return no rows, hen the result is `NULL`.  However, that is not happening here, because the subquery is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`, so it always returns one row.

So, use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT s.member, SUM(s.revenue) AS payment,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s2.revenue), 0)
        FROM statistics s2
        WHERE s2.referral = s.member AND
              s2.date >= '2019-04-01' AND
              s2.date < '2019-05-01'
       ) AS aff_earnings,
       (SELECT m.paypal
        FROM members m
        WHERE m.id = s.member
       ) AS paypal 
FROM statistics s
WHERE s.date >= '2019-04-01' AND
      s.date < '2019-05-01'
GROUP BY s.member;
```

Notes:

- I added table aliases to uniquely identify each table.
- I qualified all column names, so their source table is unambiguous.
- I fixed the date arithmetic, both by introducing standard date formats and simplifying the logic for defining the month range.

Comment: Awesome!  Selected answer :)  By the way, how would I add `aff_earnings` and `payment`?  I tried doing `payment + aff_earnings AS total` but got an error.

Comment: @Stacker . . . You can use a subquery for that. Column aliases cannot be used in expressions in the same `select` where they are defined.